# How do I perform the mission "Pause with a starfruit in play" in fruit ninja?

Tags: fruit-ninja

I tried to complete this mission many times. I kept holding the starfruit. I did not slice any other fruit after slicing a starfruit. I tried these two ways but it did not work. I don't understand the mission. So I need help.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to literally pause the game with a starfruit in play?

Comment: Yeah seams that is what they are asking for, have a starfruint on screen and hit pause button.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to test this (I kept skipping the missions until I got this one) and found that you literally need to pause the game using the pause button while a Starfruit is on the screen.  After I did that, it showed that I completed the mission both in the pause screen, and after the game was finished.